# Real Exchange Rate Cross Rate

Tags: exchange-rates

I have to do a study to determine the real exchange rate . I've read about the purchasing power parity and the interest rate parity . I also found the cross rate formula and was wondering if the result I get after applying this formula is a real exchange rate or nominal one ? If not can anyone recommend me a 3rd method ? Thanks !